# How to build Float32Array from ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, web-worker

Consider I have an ArrayBuffer, as shown in next screenshot)

[image: Screenshot from google developers console]

```
//recompute object from vertices and normals
const verticesBuffer:ArrayBuffer = e.data.verticesBufferArray;
const normalsBuffer:ArrayBuffer = e.data.normalsBufferArray;

const vertices = new Float32Array(verticesBuffer);
const normals = new Float32Array(normalsBuffer);
```

But at this point vertices and normals are undefined. So, variables vertices and normals are undefined while verticesBuffer and normalBuffer are ok.

On the conversion I get following error

```
const vertices = new Float32Array(verticesBuffer);
```

> Uncaught RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 39744

So question is **how to pass from verticesBuffer:ArrayBuffer to vertices:Float32Array ?**

Thanks!

Comment: How are `e.data.verticesBufferArray` and `e.data.normalsBufferArray` set to some value?

Comment: @Pointy they are sent through a WebWorker, I have not written the code to avoid messing too much. Data arrives correctly.

Comment: How does data arrive correctly if you say that the value is `undefined` instead of a buffer?

Comment: Hello @Bergi buffer is ok. But when I try to create const vertices = new Float32Array(verticesBuffer); (from the buffer), vertices is undefined. So, it is the conversion from the buffer to the Float32Array what does not work.

Comment: @AlbertoValero Are you sure there? A `new` expression never produces `undefined`. We'd need a [mcve] to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi Making close examine I get undefined because I get an uncaught exception: Uncaught RangeError: Invalid typed array length: 39744. So problem is related with the length, I have seen there is an optional parameter in the Float32Array constructor. I will play with it.

Comment: OK, that sounds more real. Please [edit] your question to include that error message - of course the variables don't get assigned a value after an exception.

Comment: Shouldn't big typed arrays and buffers be transferred as "transferrable objects" and not through the serialization mechanism anyway?

Comment: @Pointy an ArrayBuffer is a transferable object. That's why I am doing all this.

Comment: The thing is you've posted a very limited amount of code; it's not obvious how you're transferring it. All we know is that you've got a problem.

Comment: @Pointy forget about the transfer. Transfer is done right (it is checked). Problem does not lay on the transfer, but on the conversion from ArrayBuffer to Float32Array. Error is here: const vertices = new Float32Array(verticesBuffer);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  const vertexCount = verticesBuffer.byteLength / 4;
  const normalCount = normalsBuffer.byteLength / 4;

  const vertices = Float32Array.from(verticesBuffer, 0, vertexCount);
  const normals = Float32Array.from(normalsBuffer, 0, normalCount);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: If I'm reading the docs right, `new Float32Array(buffer)` creates a view on an existing data, while `Float32Array.from(...)` instantiates a new buffer. It seems to me like an unnecessary copying is happening in the proposed solution.